# Seleccionar en macro rectángulo de hoja específica

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo el siguiente código para cambiar el relleno de un rectángulo según el valor de una celda de la **hoja 2** de excel:

```
If Sheets(2).Range("H4") = "0" Then

   

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 58")).Select
        With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
    
    Else
    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 58")).Select
        With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
    
    End If
```

La cuestión es que el rectángulo se encuentra en la **hoja 1**. Como puedo cambiar

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 58")).Select
```

Para que no seleccione el rectángulo de la hoja activa, sino el de la **hoja 1**

Comment: ¿Has probado con `Worksheets("Hoja1").Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 58")).Select`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes hacer un método tipo: (No estoy seguro de que funcione, y no puedo probarlo ahora, inténtalo así, a ver

```
Sub SeleccionarHoja()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range(Array("Rectangle 58")).Select
End Sub
```